# Shall keep the table header if it's an empty table?

Tags: tables, data, header, empty

I got the feedback from UX expert who suggested displaying the table header even though that there is no data created, UX expert thought if have table header, user can foresee what kind of information will be there when data is created.

But I am not fully agree, I will do a few user interview to get more feedbacks on this. Before that, I'd like to hear your opinion.

There are two empty data use scenaiors are considered in design

**No data created**
The whole table is invisible, includes the search and filter.
Only displays the instruction information and create data button

**No data found**
The table header is visible.
Displays the information, something like "No data found, try to change the search and filter."

Comment: What is the difference between "No data created" and "No data found" from a user's perspective? Sounds to me as if the columns are there in both cases (and you could display them)

Comment: Yes, Nash. Basically they are same, if further speaking, it's a minor difference I'd like to indicate users. "No data created" that tells there has no data added yet, currently nothing provsioned. However, "No data found" tells  there is no that one specific data found after filtered.

Comment: Also headers or no headers gives a different signal:
showing table headers shows the user that it's an empty table.
Showing nothing shows that there is no table, not even an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

Do both.

Show the instruction and button above the table. But also show the tabel. This is why:

- Give an impression of what you have to offer and what they can expect. "No promises, you can see it is actually here but we need you to add some data first."
- Familiarize users with the (for them new) design. The empty table teaches users how data is presented which adds to the motivation to actually use it.
- Create a more vibrant experience. If you see the table growing with just a first item, it can provide confirmation that it is working and how it is working. It also makes it more fun to use.

See also this nice article [about designing empty states](https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/why-empty-states-deserve-more-design-time/) .

Comment: @ jazZRo,Thanks for your suggestions and attached article. I think you made some points. Will read through that